# Как зациклить массив? Java

Tags: java, массивы, циклы

Есть массив из `n` элементов, и есть массив из `k` элементов, так вот, мне нужно что бы `К` массив заполнялся элементами из `n`, но при условии что `n < k`

Мне нужно что бы следующие индексы массива n ходили по кругу, типа `arr[n + 1] = arr[0]`, `arr[n + 2] = arr[1]` и т.д. Нужно как то зациклить массив. Думал может какой-нибудь алгоритм придумать в цикле, который бы обнулял индекс, но возможно есть попроще вариант?

Для более ясного варианта в массиве строк есть 5 элементов, и есть массив из допустим 12 элементов,

```
arr1 = {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e");
```

то после цикла второй массив должен иметь такой вид

```
arr2 = {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "a", "b");`
```

Comment: эм... `k%n`? Вы это хотели?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] arr1 = new String[] {
        "a", "b", "c", "d", "e"
    };
    String[] arr2 = new String[12];
    for (int i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
        arr2[i] = arr1[i % arr1.length];
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(b));
}
```

Comment: *facepalm* все было настолько просто.. Спасибо!